# Need jquery to wait on ajax but async : false isn't working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a view that opens on button click to display db results. I want to disable the button while the results are returned, then enable it once the section is filled. However, it disables then enables the button before the view gets filled out and people keep clicking the button multiple times - which then causes the section to toggle in/out multiple times. Here is the code I'm using:

```
$('#ViewComments').click(function () {
$("#ViewComments").prop("disabled", true); // Disable View Comments button after click
var tr = $('tr');
$("#CommentResults").find(tr).remove();
$("#InsertComment").focus();
var parcel_id = $('#ParcelId').val();
$.ajax({
    url: "classes/get-comments.php?parcel_id=" + parcel_id,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    async : false,
    error: function (SMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("An error has occurred making the request: " + errorThrown);
    },
    success: function (comments) {
        for (var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) {
            var tr = $('<tbody></tbody>');
            if (comments[i].comment == null || comments[i].comment == "") {
                tr.append("<tr><td><span class='comment1'>Entered By: " + comments[i].name + "</span></td><td style=\"text-align:left; width:25%;\"><span class='comment1'>" + comments[i].date_created + "</span></td></tr><tr><td colspan=\"2\"><span style=\"font-style:italic;\">No comment entered.</span></td></tr>");
            } else {
                tr.append("<tr><td><span class='comment1'>Entered By: <span class='comment2'>" + comments[i].name + "</span></span></td><td style=\"text-align:left; width:75%\"><span class='comment1'>" + comments[i].date_created + "</span></td></tr><tr><td colspan=\"2\">" + comments[i].comment + "</td></tr>");
            } 
            $('#CommentResults').append(tr);
        }
        $('#Comments').slideToggle('slow');
    }
    });//end ajax call
//});
$("#ViewComments").prop("disabled", false); // re-enable View Comments button 
}); //end view comments click function
```

Any help or ideas is appreciated. Thx in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do a jQuery blocking AJAX call without async = false?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062803/how-do-i-do-a-jquery-blocking-ajax-call-without-async-false)

Comment: Can I ask why you want it to be synchronous? and is this a typo in the error callback: `SMLHttpRequest`? - should it not be `XMLHttpRequest` (bearing in mind it doesn't appear to be utilized)?

Answer (score 1):

You should move the 
`$("#ViewComments").prop("disabled", false); // re-enable View Comments button` into the success and error callbacks. Otherwise, the button just gets re-enabled as soon as the AJAX request is initiated, not when it completes. Here us my update to your code:

```js
$('#ViewComments').click(function () {
$("#ViewComments").prop("disabled", true); // Disable View Comments button after click
var tr = $('tr');
$("#CommentResults").find(tr).remove();
$("#InsertComment").focus();
var parcel_id = $('#ParcelId').val();
$.ajax({
    url: "classes/get-comments.php?parcel_id=" + parcel_id,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    async : false,
    error: function (SMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("An error has occurred making the request: " + errorThrown);
         $("#ViewComments").prop("disabled", false); // re-enable View Comments button 
    },
    success: function (comments) {
        for (var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) {
            var tr = $('<tbody></tbody>');
            if (comments[i].comment == null || comments[i].comment == "") {
                tr.append("<tr><td><span class='comment1'>Entered By: " + comments[i].name + "</span></td><td style=\"text-align:left; width:25%;\"><span class='comment1'>" + comments[i].date_created + "</span></td></tr><tr><td colspan=\"2\"><span style=\"font-style:italic;\">No comment entered.</span></td></tr>");
            } else {
                tr.append("<tr><td><span class='comment1'>Entered By: <span class='comment2'>" + comments[i].name + "</span></span></td><td style=\"text-align:left; width:75%\"><span class='comment1'>" + comments[i].date_created + "</span></td></tr><tr><td colspan=\"2\">" + comments[i].comment + "</td></tr>");
            } 
            $('#CommentResults').append(tr);
        }
        $('#Comments').slideToggle('slow');
        $("#ViewComments").prop("disabled", false); // re-enable View Comments button 
    }
    });//end ajax call
//});
}); //end view comments click function
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="ViewComments">View comments</button>
<button id="InsertComment">View comments</button>
<div>ParcelID: <input id="ParcelId" value="5" type="Number /></div>
<div id="Comments">
     <div id="CommentResults"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: well, no, it gets re enabled after, but what's happening is the change isn't rendered due to the ajax blocking with `async: false`. but removing async: false and using the complete callback to re-enable it would do what you're suggesting.